# Python code to change the background color of html

Tags: python, html, formatting

I have created a dashboard using python. I have a requirement to make some cosmetic changes in the html page.

1. Change the font and size
2. Changing the background color
3. Putting one company logo.

I researched with `turtle` and `tkinter`,and installed the same but the system is not recogonizing the modules. Is there a way to achieve the above functionality.
Source code is as below

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import requests
import json
import datetime
import sys
import os
from html import HTML
todayDate=datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
h=HTML('html','')
p=h.p('DETAILS for ',' ', todayDate)
t=h.table(border='1')
r=t.tr()
r.td('Import Timestamp')
r.td('JobId')
r.td('Status')
r.td('RecordsProcessed')
r.td('RecordsFailed')
r.td('FileName')
r.td('Duration')
r.td('Throughput')
print '\n'
def genHTMLforImportSuccess():
                responseurl = requests.get(url)
                if(responseurl.ok):
                        jData = json.loads(responseurl.content)
                        if jData > 0:
                                for responseurl in jData['response']:
                                        starttime=responseurl['statistics']['startTime']
                                        jobId= responseurl['jobId']
                                        status = responseurl['status']
                                        recordsProcessed=responseurl['statistics']['recordsProcessed']
                                        recordsFailed=responseurl['statistics']['recordsFailed']
                                        fileName=responseurl['fileName']
                    duration=responseurl['statistics']['duration']
                    throughput=responseurl['statistics']['throughput']
                                        print '\n'
                                        r=t.tr()
                                        r.td(str(starttime))
                                        r.td(str(jobId))
                                        r.td(str(status))
                                        r.td(str(recordsProcessed))
                                        r.td(str(recordsFailed))
                                        r.td(str(fileName))
                    r.td(str(duration))
                    r.td(str(throughput))
                                        print '\n'
                        else:
                                print "No data feed"
                else:
                        responseurl.raise_for_status()
genHTMLforImportSuccess()
print h
```

Any help is highly appreciated

I added the below code after the 
from html import HTML

```
html = """
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>testpage </title>
<style>
body {
    background-color: aqua;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
"""
```

but could not get the desired result.how can i fix this

Comment: why do you need `turtle` and `tkinter` ? They have nothing to do with `HTML`.

Comment: if you need to change color and fonts in HTML then learn `CSS` and `<style> </style>`

Comment: as for me some template (ie. `Jinja`) or even normal string formatting would be more readable then `html` module

Comment: @furas, how to incoporate the css or style in python.any sample code you can provide as an example

Comment: `HTML` code to set red background `<head> <style> body {background-color: red} </style> </head>`.

Comment: @furas, this i understtod,but how i can make the html tag inside python code.

Comment: :) :) :) you use `html` module and you do ie. `td()` which creates HTML tag `<td> </td>`, and  `table()` which creates HTML tag `<table> </table>`, etc. So maybe try `head()` and `style()`. If it doesn't work then find documentation for module `html` for information.